# Ruby select string from array

Tags: ruby

I am basically trying to select every string in an array that matches a particular string.

I am currently using the following code, but as you guys know, this only gives an array of the indexes of the elements that evaluate to true. I want the actual string at that position.

```
arr.each_index.select{|i| arr[i].chars.sort.join == someString}
```

Comment: pls provide sample data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr.select { |s| s == "some string" }
```

An example:

```
arr = %w(One Two Three Two Two)

arr.select { |x| x == "Two" }
 => ["Two", "Two", "Two"]
```

Comment: I have tried this, when I do that I get a Type Error "Can't convert string into integer"